# C fork and pipe add numbers from a file

Tags: c, pipe, fork

Totals different for same file when executed.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 100
#define RUNS 1

int main() {    
    int num,i;
    FILE *fp;
    char*s, buf[1024];
    int count =0;
    char c;
    char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME];
    printf("Enter filename: ");
    scanf ("%s",filename);
    if ((fp =fopen(filename, "r"))  == NULL)    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&num);
    for (c = getc(fp); c!= EOF; c = getc(fp))
    {
        if (c == '\n'){
            count = count+1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s has %d numbers \n", filename, count);
    int f;
    printf("Choose from the options how many processes you want to use [1,2,4]: ");
    scanf("%i", &f);
    printf("%i processes \n", f);
    int fds[f+1][2];
    int numb[count];
    int x,k;
    time_t start, finish;
    start = time(NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < RUNS; i++)
    {
        pipe(fds[f]);
        for( x = 0; x<f; x++)
        {
            pipe(fds[x]);
            int ind[2];
            ind[0] = ((x)*(count/f));
            ind[1] = ((x+1)*(count/f));
            write(fds[x][1], &ind, 2* sizeof(int));
            if (fork() ==0)
            {
                int t =0;
                int ind2[2];
                read(fds[x][0], &ind2, 2*sizeof(int));
                for( k = ind2[0]; k<ind2[1]; k++)
                {
                    t += numb[k];
                }
                write(fds[f][1], &t, sizeof(int));
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        int m, tmp, total;
        total = 0;
        for( m = 0; m < f; m++)
        {

        for( m = 0; m < f; m++)
        {
            read(fds[f][0], &tmp, sizeof(int));
            sleep(5);
            total += tmp;
        }
        printf("DOne calc \n");
        printf("Total: %i \n", total);
    }
    finish = time(NULL);
    float runtime = (float)((finish-start)/RUNS);
    printf("runtime: %f \n", runtime);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You have `for( m = 0; m < f; m++)` twice, so you have unmatching braces.

Comment: That is not C#.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Also please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) more urgently.  You've met one part of the MCVE criteria — some code.  There's no explanation of the data file used as input, nor what you expect as output, nor what you get as output, and there isn't anything in there that is formally a question (nowhere where you typed a question mark).  So, you've not yet asked a question.  We're not likely to answer things that aren't questions.

Answer (score 1):

You get random result for the same input because the calculation based on uninitialized `int numb[count];` values.

According to the C99 standard, section 6.7.8.10:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Because of it `int numb[count];` contains some random junk from memory. To get predictive results use explicit initialization:

```
#include <string.h>  // memset

int numb[count]; 
memset (numb, 0, sizeof(numb));  // Zero-fills
```

Use the code bellow to put numbers from `filename` file into `numb`:

```
int i = 0;
char line[1024];
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) ) 
{
  if( sscanf(line, "%d", &numb[i]) == 1 )  // One number per line 
  {
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: When I tried to initialize as u recommended,  it gave me this   
int numb[count]={0};
fork.c:42:5: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
fork.c:42:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘numb’) [enabled by default]

Comment: @AjayaShrestha That is my mistake, variable size arrays cannot be initialized with `= {0}`. Answer updated.

Comment: are you sure that sizeof with size array work as you want ? I will replace by `sizeof *numb * count`

Comment: @Stargateur I'm sure, `sizeof(numb)` will return `sizeof(int) * count`.

Comment: Enter filename: file1.dat
file1.dat has 1000 numbers
Choose from the options how many processes you want to use [1,2,4]: 1
1 processes
count : 1000, numb: -2089032624
ind0= 0 , ind1 = 1000
ind22 14372880
 t: 816703723, numb[k]: -2089032624, ind2[0]: 0, ind2[1] : 1000
t2: 816703723
 DOne calc
Total: 816703723
t: 5
 It is giving me weird numbers

Comment: Enter filename: file1.dat
file1.dat has 1000 numbers
Choose from the options how many processes you want to use [1,2,4]: 1
1 processes
count : 1000, numb: -1380689600
ind0= 0 , ind1 = 1000
ind22 33976336
 t: -2015298183, numb[k]: -1380689600, ind2[0]: 0, ind2[1] : 1000
t2: -2015298183
 DOne calc
Total: -2015298183
t: 5
tried again and giving me random numbers thus giving random totals

Comment: @AjayaShrestha Have you added initialization of `numb` array as I suggest in the answer? In the code above `numb` array values are never updated, total should be always `0`. Do you read values from the file and store it into `numb`? If so please add this code to the code above.

Comment: Somehow numbers from files are not getting populated in numb. Numb is just throwing random numbers. Tried adding initialization for numb but it keeps saying variable size arrays cannot be initialized. Can you look into my code and help me with how to populate the numb.

Comment: @AjayaShrestha Use `memset (numb, 0, sizeof(numb));` to add default `numb` initialization. Is `file1.dat` should be the source of numbers for `numb` array?

Comment: @AjayaShrestha I've added a sample of how you could read numbers into `numb`. Check my updated answer.